# AngularJS: is this a bad practice for authentification?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, cookies

I'm new in AngularJS. I use Drupal as Backend for APIs.

So this is my problem:

When the user is logged-in, Drupal saves automatically the SessionNAME = SessionID in the cookie to keep the user logged-in so on refresh the user is still logged-in but i loose the userId, the username, his email, his favorite movies...

My solution was: sending a request to the server in `app.run()` to get logged user data and I store these data in AuthetificationService.currentUser so if a user is logged i will have all his data otherwise currentUser will be NULL.

Is that a bad practise?

NOTE: Please if your suggestion will be webStorage or cookieStorage tell me exactly what i need to store and when i need to empty the cookie or the local-storage.

Comment: Try to use Token based authentication. Keep user's token into browser's sessionstorage and on closing tab or browser , token will automatically removed

Comment: As I know Token based authentification is basically sending the token in the header of every request (correct me if I'm wrong). This guarantee that a user is logged in or not. But my problem how i keep user important data in angular after refresh. I dont want to call the server to get those data on every refresh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the practice I follow and is usually used:

1. Login->

create session on server ->
store the user object and important info in localstorage
e.g.

```
localStorage.setObject("myApp_user",user); 
localStorage.setObject("myApp_movies",movies);
```

1. Refresh Page (check session)
   check session(if logged in) -> 
   get the user data from localStorage and use it
   e.g

   `UserService.user = localStorage.getObject("myApp_user");
   MoviesService.movies = localStorage.getObject("myApp_movies");`
2. Logout
   close session call on server->remove cookies->remove data from localStorage.. e.g.
   `localStorage.removeItem("myApp_user");
   localStorage.removeItem("myApp_movies");`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello again, Thank you for this clear answer but I have still 2 more questions: #1 check session(if logged in) you mean check if sessionID exists in cookies? #2 Since the user can modify localStorage values and I want to store the users' role this is not secure anymore a free user can change his role to premium?

Comment: Answer1: Yes. have to check the sessionId
Answer2: The roles and secure info is never stored in localStorage :) only the basic information, such as profile basic info, profile image, etc.. 
Passwords/secure info have to be fetched and stored on/from the server